# Flutter Firebase creating a useful instance

Tags: firebase, flutter

should I call it by creating a new instance every time I need it, as in the firebase documents
like this = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentuser

or should I create this statically on another page and always call the same instance?
like this = static FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance
Page1:
_auth.currentuser
Page2:
_auth.currentuser

or should I define this as registerLazySingleton with the Get_it package in one place(I don't know get_it so this may be wrong)

Or if there is a more useful way, I would like to find out, isn't it harmful to create different instances all the time?

Answer (score 2):

Calling `FirebaseAuth.instance` doesn't create a new instance. It just returns the current instance of the default [FirebaseApp] configured with the app.

Ideally, you wouldn't want to call `FirebaseAuth.instance` every time you need to access FirebaseUser object, but you can call it at least once per class to keep it clean. It shouldn't affect the performance of your app.